# Flask-Admin: Form scaffolding per-request

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

## The scenario

I'm creating a CRUD interface using Flask-Admin. I'm using `flask.session` to determine the role of the currently logged in user. Based on this role, I want to scaffold forms/views differently per request.

## Code

index.py

```
from institution import InstitutionView

app = flask.Flask(...)

admin = flask_admin.Admin(...)

# artificial user data
user_dict = {
    ...
    'role' : 'Teacher'
}

# pass user data to institution view
institutionView = InstitutionView(..., user=user_dict)
admin.add_view(institutionView)
```

institution.py

```
class InstitutionView(ModelView):
    ...

    def scaffold_list_columns(self):
        # generate columns dynamically
        if self._user['admin_role'] == 'Teacher':
            return ('name', 'c_date', 'e_date')
        return ('name', 'foo', 'bar', 'c_date', 'e_date')

    def scaffold_form(self):
        # generate fields dynamically
        if self._user['admin_role'] == 'Teacher':
            ...
```

## The problem

Until now, I've been artificially injecting user data into the `InstitutionView` constructor. This is a problem now that I want to pull data out of `flask.session`. **Scaffolding needs to take place inside a request context**, but it currently takes place at application initialization.

I'm new to Flask, so it's quite possible that I'm going about this all wrong.

### UPDATE 2015.8.20

One possibility is to override `flask_admin.base.BaseView.render()` which is invoked at every request. However, I would need to reproduce flask-admin's form scaffolding logic within `render()` which is far from trivial (or clean).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to override two methods:

- `flask_admin.model.base.BaseView._handle_view()`
- `flask_admin.model.base.BaseModelView._refresh_cache()`

Code:

```
class InstitutionView(ModelView):
    ...

    # _handle_view called every request
    def _handle_view(self, name, **kwargs):
        if not flask_login.current_user.is_authenticated():
            return self.inaccessible_callback(name, **kwargs)

        # re-scaffold views every request
        self._refresh_cache()

        return super(InstitutionView, self)._handle_view(name, **kwargs)

    # _refresh_cache called once when view is added to admin interface
    def _refresh_cache(self):
        # do not _refresh_cache outside of a request context
        if not flask_login.current_user:
            # init members with empty tuples to avoid instantiation error
            self._list_columns = ()
            return
        super(InstitutionView, self)._refresh_cache()
```